# Do short time symbols need to be pluralised

Tags: time

We are wanting to know how to shorten time symbols/words in an open source code library.

The code will emit:

`1 second`, `2 seconds`, `1 hour`, `2 hours`, `1 week`, `2 weeks`, etc.

Is the correct shorthand `1s`, `2s`, `1h`, `2h`, `1wk`, `2wk`, for example?

I.e. should any of the short forms be plural?

Comment: It is a question of style. Follow the applicable style guide. According to some styles, units of measurement in standard abbreviation are **not** to be pluralized: 45 km., 72 in., etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, the short forms should not be plural. You write `23sec` or `23s`, not `23secs` or `23ss`.

Comment: For non-adjectival plural form, I write 23 secs, 24 hrs, 10 wks, 40 yrs. *He has been working here for 25 yrs.* vs *He has been working here for 25 yr.* I won't waste my click voting you down.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: You are free to write that, of course. But it is not the [convention](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html) followed in science for standard units. Standard unit abbreviations do not have a plural form. We write `300m`, not `300ms`, for 300 meters (the latter is 300 milliseconds). [Google](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=standard+scientific+unit+abbreviations+plural).

Comment: You have mistaken the idea of scientific convention for clarity vs layman's use for clarity. Scientifically, it is not acceptable for me to say, These bananas weigh two pounds. Scientific notation requires me to numerically write: These bananas weigh 0.9072 kilograms, or 0.9072 kg. *Pounds* is not an acceptable scientific notation for weight.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: Kris's comment is appropriate: It depends on who is reading. All we know here is that the context is an "open source code library". Metric units are standard for science and (in some countries) technology (e.g. engineering). But non-metric units are also used in both. And standard abbreviations are defined for all such, as is the convention not to change the form of a unit (any unit) based on the quantity. But if you think that "2ms" is a clearer abbreviation of "2 meters" for a layman than is "2m" then go for it. Likewise "2mins" instead of "2min" for minutes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Short forms of time notations do not have any plural forms. 1s, 2s, 500s is just fine, there is nothing like 5ss ;).

--> For hours, hrs is the plural form in short.
--> For weeks, I have no idea, but wks sounds good.